# I want to watch to the value of the parent component in the child component

Tags: vue.js

- I have a parent component that sends tabs selected by the user to the
  child component
- I want to watch the value passed by the parent
  component in the child component
- I am sure that the value of tabs
  will change according to the parent component selection

In this code, console isn't work

child component

```
props: {
    tab: ''
},
data: function () {
    return 
        tabs: this.tab,
    };
},
watch: {
     tabs: function () {
         console.log('tabs', this.tabs);
     },
},
```

parent component

```html
<table
    :tab="0">
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

in

```
data: function () {
    return 
        tabs: this.tab,
    };
},
```

the `tabs` property takes only the initial value, I recommend to use a computed property instead of data :

```
props: {
    tab: ''
},
computed:{
    tabs(){
     return this.tab;
   }
},
watch: {
     tabs: function () {
         console.log('tabs', this.tabs);
     },
},
```

or you could watch the prop directly :

```
props: {
    tab: ''
},

watch: {
     tab: function () {
         console.log('tab', this.tab);
     },
},
```

**Note** that you shouldn't use HTML native elements as vue component like `table`

if the prop is an object or an array you should add `deep` option like :

```
props: {
    tab: ''
},
computed:{
    tabs(){
     return this.tab;
   }
},
watch: {
     tabs:{
      handler: function () {
         console.log('tabs', this.tabs);
     },
    deep:true
    }
},
```

Comment: I get the same result, the value of my tab is only one of the three numbers 0, 1, and 2

Comment: change `tab: ''` to `tab: Number`

Comment: sorry, I got the same result, I try this , I put the same console in the click event at child component i can get the value in console but isn't work in watch function

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach

```
props: {
    tab: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
},
data() {
    return {
        tabs: this.tab,
    };
},
watch: {
     tab(newVal) {
         this.tabs = newVal;
         console.log('tabs', newVal);
     },
},
```

Comment: sorry,I used this method and I still can't get the console  value

Comment: Have you replace the native element 'table'  from your parent component?

Comment: Also are you sure if your value is changing in the parent component?

Comment: Yes, I changed another name in the parent componet

Comment: I  put  the same console in the click event of the child component, when I switch the tab in the parent component and click the event in the child component, I will get different tab values, but in the watch function, I cannot get the console value